# Should atlas be renamed to qgis-atlas?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags

Of the 68 questions tagged with [`atlas`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atlas), 39 have been asked this year. When searching for a tag and typing in `qgis` however, the `atlas` tag doesn't appear, despite being explicitly labelled as referring to the QGIS plugin. Meanwhile a number of qgis plugins with fewer questions such as `qgis2leaf`, `qgis2web`, etc, have `qgis` within their names.

So should `atlas` be renamed to `qgis-atlas`?

Could it be useful for the GIS.se community to have an `atlas` tag that refers to traditional, printed-on-paper, atlases?

Comment: There appears to be no clear consensus on this so I have set [meta-tag:status-deferred].

Answer (score 5):

I might be in the minority, but I believe that tags should have names, that users actually use. There is no point in making tag-names which will not be used by the Question writers.

Before we rename the tag, we should ask whether users actually use the name qgis-Atlas or just Atlas? I haven't used this functionality much, but all I know is that it is just a tab in the print composer. There isn't a plugin called qgis-Atlas. Hence we should not rename it.

In the case of qgis2leaf & qgis2web, these are the actual names of the plugins, and hence those are the names which people use, and hence the tag names are correct.

Comment: Valid point. I do wonder about the ambiguity of these QGIS function names that could refer to other things.

Comment: I upvoted this because I agree strongly that, unless they are ambiguous, tags should reflect names that users use.  However, I notice that ["qgis atlas" has been used in posts here 35 times](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22qgis+atlas%22).  Hopefully we'll hear from one or more QGIS developers as to whether they think the [tag:atlas] tag needs to be further qualified.

Comment: Imho, either tag is fine. I don't see a strong need to change the existing tag right now.